# ANTLR4 an optional symbol at begining of a rule

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4, grammar

I'm learning how ANTLR4 works. I don't understand how to deal with optional symbol at the very beginning of a rule.

I have this simple grammar:

```
genericRule: optional otherPart ;

optional: ( 'A' | 'B' | 'C' ) * ;
otherPart: 'D' | 'E' | 'F' ;
```

When i try to match the string with only the char `'E'` the Parse Tree Inspector gives me this result:

[image: Wrong result]

How i can exclude the first empty rule `optional` if my input doesn't start with optional tokens `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'` ?

I would like to have this Parse Tree:

[image: Correct result]

Comment: I'm confused: why are you calling the "wrong result" wrong? It looks to me like it is working as it is calling your `"E"` a genericRule token.

Comment: Try `genericRule: optional? otherPart ;`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, It's working, but i don't want the empty branch `optional`

Comment: @LexLi With your rule i have a warning: `rule genericRule contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string`. I don't want to match the empty string

Comment: Why my question is bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring the "optional" part up a level (to the place where it's optional)

```
grammar ExprParser;

genericRule: optional* otherPart ;

optional:  'A' | 'B' | 'C'  ;
otherPart: 'D' | 'E' | 'F' ;
```

[image]

In your grammar you've said `genericRule` MUST have an `optional` node (and that the `optional` node may not have any content (children)).

Comment: Thanks, now it works as expected. So the level in which the `*` is inserted matters

Comment: definitely... yes.  I always find a rule with a top-level * (or an empty alternative) to be something of a "code smell" in a grammar.  It's not always wrong, there can be reasons why you might prefer a node on the tree to always be there even if it's effectively empty, but it's rare.